# Multipeer connectivity in iOS

Tags: ios, networking, bonjour

Let's say I have a windows PC which is connected wired to enterprise network. This PC broadcasting a text file using Bonjour. I want to be able to receive this file when iPhone connects on enterprises network wifi. 
Let's say I use push model so the PC broadcasting from a service running on it.

My question: may I use multipeer connectivity framework in my iPhone app?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/2619912) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To discover Bonjour services on the network from the phone, use [`NSNetServiceBrowser`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/index.html). Multipeer Connectivity will not let you advertise a service from a Windows machine.

Once you have discovered your service with `NSNetServiceBrowser`, you can setup a session to it using the normal network mechanisms (for example, by starting a small HTTP server on your Windows machine).